# using iTextSharp.ShowTextAligned() to add watermark

Tags: itext

We want to add a water mark with user email & name on top of our pdf before we send it. I've written code that does that and it is working great. I want to check if this is the best way of doing this. We want the water mark to be split into two lines at the top of the pdf.

, I used "ShowTextAligned()" twice with different "y" coordinates to achieve that.

```
    private MemoryStream StampPdf(string pdfPath, string name, string email)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        var pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);

        var textAngle = 0;
        var fontSize = 14;
        var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        var watermarkLine1 = "Personal use only for " + name;
        var watermarkLine2 = "at " + email;


        using (stamper)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                var mediaBox = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                var overContent = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                overContent.BeginText();
                overContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                overContent.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
                overContent.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, watermarkLine1, 10, mediaBox.Top - 20, textAngle);
                overContent.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, watermarkLine2, 10, mediaBox.Top - 40, textAngle);
                overContent.EndText();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        stamper.Close();
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

I want to confirm two things:

1. "Is it possible to use ShowTextAligned() to wrap text that reaches the end of the line?"
2. "Does ShowTextAligned() honor carriage return/newline?"

Thanks,

-Samah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to question 1.: No, you need the `ColumnText` object to do that.

Answer to question 2.: No, `showTextAligned()` ignores newline characters.